# Page factory technique using selenium property file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I m confused.

As automation framework if i use page object model /page factory than i should use object repository I mean Properties file in selenium webdriver. or i can use one at a time either page factory or properties file approach.

Regards,
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

In automation frameworks it is almost always a good thing to go for Page Objects. It helps to keep test code clean and DRY. It is the way you organize/ reflect aplication behavior to test structure.

PageFactory helps you to initialize controls in Page Objects. It uses selectors you specify in your classes.

Technically there is nothing stopping you from using properties files to keep your selectors away from Page Objects if you would like to. I can imagine situations when that would work pretty smoothly.

On the other hand - selectors in Page Objects are easier to maintain, since you have them always in context defined by given Page. So if there are changes in application - you go to the Page Object, which represents that page and change your selectors.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, it is two different things.

Here is reference to [Selenium PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, since both approaches are different